# Adding authenticated attributes using MS CryptoApi

Tags: signing, cryptoapi, pkcs#7

I'm struggling adding authenticated attributes (OCSP data) to my message using CryptoApi. I first used CryptoApi's simplified message functions, but now switch to the low-level message functions, thinking that I would be able to control the message structure better. But I am once again stuck. My process is as follows:

- Initialize CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO and CMSG_SIGNED_ENCODE_INFO structure
- I create a CRYPT_ATTRIBUTE for the ocsp date and specifies it in the CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO structure
- I then call CryptMsgCalculateEncodedLength to get the size
- CryptMsgOpenToEncode with CMSG_SIGNED as the message type
- CryptMsgUpdate, to insert my content into the message
- CryptMsgGetParam with CMSG_CONTENT_PARAM to get the encoded blob
- CryptMsgClose, I'm done with the message for now.

I open the message again to get the CMSG_ENCRYPTED_DIGEST, which is sent to a TSA and the result is added as an unaunthenticated attribute using CryptMsgControl.

I'm using this to sign signature tags in Adobe. So when there is no authenticated attributes, I receive three green check from Adobe:

1. The document has not been modified...
2. The document is signed by the current user
3. The signature includes an embedded timestamp (and the timestamp is validate)

But as soon as the authenticated attribute is added the signer's identity is invalidated and the timestamp data in incorrect. The CMSG_COMPUTED_HASH_PARAM when authenticated attributes are added and when not, differs. Should this not be the same? Since the document digest is of the content of the document and not of the authenticated attribute.

Is there another way to add authenticated attributes? I've tried to add it as a signer using CryptMsgControl, but that did not help either...

Answer (score 0):

how about this step on adding the authenticated attributes for signing, example time stamping,

```
CryptEncodeObject(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, szOID_RSA_signingTime, &curtime, pTime, &szTime);
pTime = (BYTE *)LocalAlloc(GPTR, szTime);
CryptEncodeObject(PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, szOID_RSA_signingTime, &curtime, pTime, &szTime);
time_blob.cbData = szTime;
time_blob.pbData = pTime;
attrib[0].pszObjId = szOID_RSA_signingTime;
attrib[0].cValue = 1;
attrib[0].rgValue = &time_blob;
CosignerInfo.cAuthAttr = 1;
CosignerInfo.rgAuthAttr = attrib;
```

and that Cosigner params is from CMSG_SIGNER_ENCODE_INFO CosignerInfo;